# Очистить textarea на js

Tags: javascript, html

Добра, помогите очистить форму после выполнения функции?

После того как форма сработала кнопка "отправить" я вызываю функцию getks() она работает даже в ней после получения данных я очистить форму. Пробовал по разному, не получается.

Форма:

```
<div class="container-xl">
        <h1>Не фига себе</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <form id='getform'>
                    <textarea id="getarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                    </br>
                    <input id="get" type="button" value="Отправить" onclick="getks()">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <p id='ks2'></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
<script>

    function getks() {
        var getform = document.getElementById('getform');
        var ks = document.getElementById('getarea');
        var ks2 = document.getElementById('ks2');
        ks2.innerHTML = ks.value;
        console.log(ks);
        ks.value.innerHTML = '';
        //console.log(getform);
        //ks.innerHTML = '';
        //document.getform.reset();
    }

</script>
```

Спасибо =) извините (

Answer (score 2):

Все гениальное просто:

```
document.getElementById('getform').reset();
```